# BSTree add function

Tags: c++

I am trying to do the add function in BSTree.However, I have no idea where to start. Can anyone give me some hints which part I need to consider first. I don't know where is the new Pair(key, value); to use and what is the using Tree::data;. I just want to get the hints but not the answer. Thank you.

Below is the Pair.h file

```
#ifndef PAIR_H_
#define PAIR_H_

//a key-value pair
//this simple class is pretty much self-explanatory
//all its implementation is already given
template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class Pair
{
public:
    Pair(KeyType k, ValueType v) :
            key(k), value(v)
    {
    }

    KeyType getKey() const
    {
        return key;
    }

    void setKey(KeyType key)
    {
        this->key = key;
    }

    ValueType getValue() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    void setValue(ValueType value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }

private:
    KeyType key;
    ValueType value;
};

#endif /* PAIR_H_ */
```

Below is the Tree.h

```
template<typename Container, typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class Tree
{
public:
    virtual bool add(KeyType key, ValueType value) = 0; //pure virtual     function here, description can be found in BSTree class
    virtual bool remove(KeyType key) = 0; //pure virtual function here, description can be found in BSTree class
    virtual ValueType getValue(KeyType key) = 0; //pure virtual function here, description can be found in BSTree class
    virtual ~Tree(){}; //an empty destructor

protected:
    Container data; //the data container (a vector, which is either a ListVector or ArrayVector in this assignment)
                    //that stores all the node data of the tree
                    //how the node is stored in the data container is very specific
                    //please refer to the webpage description for details

    //treeToString in Utility is this class's only friend... :(
    template<typename aContainer, typename aKeyType, typename aValueType>
    friend string treeToString(Tree<aContainer, aKeyType, aValueType>* tree);
};

#endif
```

Below is the BSTree.h file

```
#ifndef BSTREE_H_
#define BSTREE_H_

#include "Tree.h"
#include "Pair.h"
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

//the Binary Search Tree class
//the keys have to be unique in the tree - you need to make sure of that when performing the insertion
template<typename Container, typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class BSTree : public Tree<Container, KeyType, ValueType>
{
public:
BSTree(){};
~BSTree();
//add a node to the tree, according to the given key and value
//you have to use the exact algorithm described in the lecture notes
//so that you will have the exact same result as our demo and sample output
//it should do nothing to the tree and return false when there is already a node that has the same key
//otherwise, it should add the node and return true
//hint: you probably will have a statement to allocate the space for the new pair, like so: "new Pair<KeyType, ValueType>(key, value);"
bool add(KeyType key, ValueType value);
bool remove(KeyType key);
ValueType getValue(KeyType key);
int getHeight();
using Tree<Container, KeyType, ValueType>::data;
};
#include "BSTree.tpp"

#endif /* BSTREE_H_ */
```

Comment: A reasonable place to start seems to be "the exact algorithm described in the lecture notes". Don't forget to "please refer to the webpage description for details".

Comment: In the notes most of the example have the root, left and right, but this do not have, so I don't know how to start.

Comment: The "webpage description" should contain information about how to encode those in a sequential container. (You're most likely going to use indexes as "pointers".)

Comment: ok, now I know how to do it. Thank you!